# Symfony remember me internals

Tags: security, symfony, fosuserbundle, remember-me

TL;DR - My problem is I am trying to manually log-in user (by Ajax request with custom action) with remember me cookie for it. Can somebody help me to do this in Symfony 3?

Hello, I am working on custom Symfony sign-up/log-in action.
First I achieved manually login user after successful sign-up by using following lines (I am using Symfony 3.1):

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
$this->get('session')->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
```

Further I would like to add remember me functionality, after short research I have found that it could be achieved by using `RememberMeToken` class. But when I use it Symfony recognizes me as `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` and not as `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` so according to this I still see log-in button and guest user menu (`is_granted` in Twig template doesn't works as expected). Can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Full code snippet:

```
if ($isKeepSigned) {
    $token = new RememberMeToken($user, 'main', $this->getParameter('secret'));
} else {
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
}

$this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
$this->get('session')->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
```

Best regards.

Besides I tried to use internal FOS user solution, but my application doesn't have services like `security.authentication.rememberme.services.persistent.'.$firewallName`
. I don't understand how it works in FOS bundle.

P.S. If some additional info is needed please let me know.

Comment: In case no answer can be found; I don't think you need to work with tokens, you can let the Symfony firewall arrange that: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

Comment: @Rvanlaak , I suppose it will not help as I am using Ajax request for login

Comment: Yes you can, as the firewall also supports different types of providers. You could even use basic http authentication as a mechanism.